# send sms to whatsapp xamarin android

Tags: xamarin.android

I want to send or text a message to a specific number in WhatsApp, and in the absence of the number or the WhatsApp customization, an error appears.

use packages

Xamarin.Forms.OpenWhatsApp

my code not work

```
var sendwhats = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button3);

            sendwhats.Click += (sender, e) => {
                var phone = textinp.Text;
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
                sendIntent.SetComponent(new ComponentName("com.whatsapp", "com.whatsapp.Conversation"));
                sendIntent.PutExtra("jid", PhoneNumberUtils.StripSeparators(phone) + "@s.whatsapp.net");without "+" prefix
                StartActivity(sendIntent);
            };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `Xamarin.Forms.OpenWhatsApp` this plugin is used in Xamarin.Forms project, it cannot be used in Xamarin.Android project.

Then, If you used Xamarin.Android project, you can use following code to send the message.

```
   private void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
           string phoneNumberWithCountryCode = "88167xxxxxxx";
            string message = "Hallo";
           StartActivity(new Intent(Intent.ActionView,
                             Uri.Parse("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + phoneNumberWithCountryCode + "&text=" + message)));
        }
```

If the phoneNumber did not be registed or existed, whatsapp will give you a alert. I can not give you a test GIF due to private policy, you can test it by youself.

Comment: Is there a modification of the code to send an image from the device memory?

Comment: If you have other question, you can open a new thread that others will see it and solve new question more quickly. If above answer is helpful, please accept it. It will help others who have similar issue.